# Why doesn't/couldn't IDictionary<TKey,TValue> implement ILookup<TKey,TValue>?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I suppose this doesn't really matter, I'm just curious.

If the difference between dictionary and lookup is one is one-to-one and the other one-to-many, wouldn't dictionary by a more specific/derived version of the other?

A lookup is a collection of key/value pairs where the key can be repeated. 
A dictionary is a collection of key/value pairs where the key cannot be repeated.

Why couldn't IDictionary implement ILookup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is mainly because the intention is different.

`ILookup<T,U>` is designed specifically to work with a collection of values.  `IDictionary<T,U>` is intended to work with a single value (that could, of course, be a collection).

While you could, of course, have `IDictionary<T,U>` implementations implement this via returning an `IEnumerable<U>` with a single value, this would be confusing, especially if your "U" is a collection itself (ie: `List<int>`).  In that case, would `ILookup<T,U>.Item` return an `IEnumerable<List<int>>`, or should it do some type of check for an `IEnumerable<T>` value type, and then "flatten" it?  Either way, it'd look confusing, and add questionable value.

Comment: It's not just "intent" that is different. A Dictionary is one value per key. An ILookup is one-or-many values per key. Also, an ILookup can only be created by a LINQ query, and is immutable; you can't add more keys or values later. (At least, as of 3.5, that was true; don't know about 4.0.)

Comment: @Cylon: ILookup is an interface - you can implement your own version of it that was not immutable, if you so choose.  As I mentioned, you *could* force `Dictionary<T,U>` to implement `ILookup<T,U>`, but it would be confusing if you did.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces `IDictionary<T,U>` and `ILookup<T,U>` both inherit `IEnumerable`.  If an `IDictionary<T,U>` is cast to `IEnumerable` and `GetEnumerator()` is called on it, the resulting enumerator should return instances of `KeyValuePair<T,U>`.  If an `ILookup<T,U>` is cast to `IEnumerable` and `GetEnumerator()` is called upon it, the resulting enumerator should return instances of `IGrouping<T,U>`.  If the `KeyValuePair<T,U>` struct were modified to implement `IGrouping<T,U>` that might be workable, but hardly clean.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because the `IDictionary'2` interface came out long before `ILookup'2` did.  Going back and modifying is unnecessary.  Concrete implementations can use `ILookup'2`.  I don't see what would be gained by modifying an interface people have been using for years.

Comment: I think you could also flip your statement around. I don't see what would be harmed by modifying the interface.  Yes, ILookup is newer, but that doesn't it mean it doesn't describe what IDictionary is doing.  Just because you and I don't see what could be gained doesn't mean it wouldn't help someone out there, it just means we can't personally see how.

Comment: What could happen if people modified the behavior of an existing and popular interface?  Oh, why no harm would come out of that.....